# Does Heidegger suggest that authenticity is an alternative to a genealogy of morals?

Tags: heidegger, nihilism, authenticity

I read Being and TIme by Heidegger but some 10 years ago now. I remember this section, because of its somewhat fascist overtones, and had another look at it (out of context) today. Page 386 of that book (the second indexed mention of the term "hero") says:

> It is not necessarily that in resoluteness one should explicitly know
>   the origin of the possibilities upon which the resoluteness projects
>   itself. It is rather in dasein's temporality, and there only, that
>   there lies any possibility that the existentiell
>   potentiality-for-Being upon which it projects itself can be gleaned
>   explicitly from the way dasein has been traditionally understood. The
>   resoluteness which comes back to itself and hands itself down, then
>   becomes the repetition of a possibility of existence that has come
>   down to us. Repeating is handing down explicitly - that is to say,
>   going back into the possibilities of the dasein that has-been-there.
>   The authentic repetition of a possibility of existence that has been -
>   the possibility that dasein may choose its hero - is grounded in
>   anticipatory resoluteness; for it is in resoluteness that one first
>   chooses the choice which makes one free for the struggle of loyally
>   following in the footsteps of that which can be repeated.

Is he suggesting that authenticity is an alternative to a genealogy of morals? That instead of asking about the "origin" of a moral belief we can ask whether we ourselves accept it out of ressentiment: or whether we are repeating the work of a "hero" - someone strong who we do not seek to injure?

Comment: One question that suggests itself to me - and hardly knowing H's work - is that to *explicitly* know a temporal origin is not the same as to know that there is a temporal origin, or indeed only to consider a temporal character; another is what does H mean by temporality - it's seems kin rather to Descarte (time as inner sense of being) - than to genealogy - a speculative history, which though famously associated with Nietzsche, seems to me to have its origin in Hegel, specifically in his history of philosophy which offers a genealogical account of philosophy.

Comment: ah i didn't know that about hegel tbh. thanks for the reply @MoziburUllah tho i'm a little lost what to do with it :)